# Making a DatePicker and timePicker appear after clicking a button

Tags: java, android

How can I make a datepicker and timepicker appear after you click on their respective editTexts? I don't want the datepicker or timepicker to appear before the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml file set your Timepicker's visibility to gone or invisible.

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then in your onClick method set it to visible

```
timePicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```